# why VectorAssembler transform is returning a column in pyspark dataframe which contains both sparse and dense vector?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, vectorization

This is the dataset df:
[image: this is the dataset df]
After `VectorAssembler` transform function as follows

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
final_vect= VectorAssembler (inputCols=['sex_indexer','smoker_indexer','day_indexer','time_indexer','size','tip'], outputCol='Independent_feature')

final_vect.transform(df).show(25)
```

this is vectorized transformed dataframe:
[image: as we can see sparse vectors in few last rows of dataset]
As we can see sparse vectors in few last rows of dataset.

why `VectorAssembler` is not working properly here. Any specific reason?
is there any other method to get vectorized data ?

Comment: Hi, have you found the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

The vectorizer actually works as expected. Spark stores vectors as [SparseVectors](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector.html) when they contain many zeros and as [DenseVectors](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.linalg.DenseVector.html) otherwise.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 3.35), (.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .5)],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
)
final_vect = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], outputCol='X')
```

```
>>> final_vect.transform(df).show(truncate=False)
+---+---+---+---+---+----+-------------------------+
|a  |b  |c  |d  |e  |f   |X                        |
+---+---+---+---+---+----+-------------------------+
|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|3.0|3.35|(6,[4,5],[3.0,3.35])     |
|0.1|0.2|0.3|0.4|0.5|0.5 |[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.5]|
+---+---+---+---+---+----+-------------------------+

>>> final_vect.transform(df).collect()
[Row(a=0.0, b=0.0, c=0.0, d=0.0, e=3.0, f=3.35, X=SparseVector(6, {4: 3.0, 5: 3.35})), Row(a=0.1, b=0.2, c=0.3, d=0.4, e=0.5, f=0.5, X=DenseVector([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5]))]
```

Spark displays a sparse vector as a 3-tuple `(size, indices, values)` where `size` is the size of the vector, `indices` is the list of indices for the value is not zero and `values` contains the corresponding values.

The way it is displayed in python when you call `collect` is a bit clearer. You can see the name of the class and it displays a dictionary of non-zero values for sparse vectors.